# Read the json file and set a variable using command line script

Tags: json, batch-file, cmd, command-line

I have the Json file called Services.json with following content:

```
{
    "name":"Services",
    "version":"1.2.0",
    "description":"Customer Services"
}
```

I want to read this file and while reading if it finds "version" key then save respective value(1.2.0) into a variable using command line script

I tried something like this but it didn't work.

```
@Echo off
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:{} " %%A in (Services.json) do (
    If "%%~A"=="version" (
      set version = "%%~b"
    )
)
pause
```

Comment: Your question has been asked, and answered before, even using a batch file. I would however strongly advise that you instead seek a solution using PowerShell. Please use the search facility at the top of the page, to locate, then adapt an answer for your purposes.

Comment: Yes, I tried those links but those doesn't seem to be same. Here in this case I want to save  version key value into a variable.

Comment: It's been done before, show us the code you've failed with, together with a link to the results you used to create it, and we'll try to assist.

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following settings for the source directory and filename are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\Q74814659.txt"

FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1,2delims=:, " %%b IN ("%filename1%") DO IF %%b=="version" SET "version=%%~c"
ECHO version=%version%

GOTO :EOF
```

It's been asked before, but it's easier for me to re-write it again that look it up.

--- Revision since the JSON file is actually 1 line

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following settings for the source directory and filename are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\Q74814659_2.txt"

SET /p json=<"%filename1%"
SET "json=%json:{=%"
SET "json=%json:}=%"
FOR %%e IN (%json%) DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=1,2delims=:" %%b in ("%%e") do FOR %%y IN (version description name) DO IF /i "%%y"==%%b SET "%%y=%%~c"
)
ECHO version=%version%
ECHO name=%name%
ECHO description=%description%

GOTO :EOF
```

rem Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.

Read the data to `json`, remove all braces, process `json` as a comma-separated list of elements `"name":"value"`

Check whether the `name` is on the list; if so, assign the `value`.

Comment: The code works as posted, so why did you change the value of `delims`? What did you change it to?

Comment: I changed the delims and could read the value of "name" but not "version" 

`FOR /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:,{}" %%b IN (D:\test\versionInfo.json) DO IF "%%~b"=="version" SET "version=%%~c"
ECHO version=%version%`

**output: version=**  It worked for "name".
`FOR /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:,{}" %%b IN (D:\test\versionInfo.json) DO IF "%%~b"=="name" SET "name=%%~c"
ECHO name=%name%`

**ouput: name=activate-enterprise-consumer-services**

Pls suggest any improvement needed to read version

Comment: I noticed that it reads this first key value in the json text. Like if I remove "name" key/value then logic is working fine.
`{
    "version":"1.2.0",
    "description":"Customer Services"
}`

Any inputs here?

Comment: Please cut-and-paste the original code. The braces (`{}`) are irrelevant and you have omitted the space from the `delims` option. It certainly works as-is for `version` and `name`. Some extra gymnastics would be required to extract `description` as the value assigned to `description` contains a space, which is one of the required delimiters.

Comment: I double checked from my end, your logic worked fine when each keyvalue pair is in a new line. The same logic didn't work, when the keyvalue pair is in a single line. May be its my bad that I posted the Json content which has new lines where as my actual content doesn't have line breaks.

Comment: Does assist a little when the test data is accurate...

Answer (score 1):

You can parse your JSON file using PowerShell and set it as a variable in your batch file with `for /f..do` loop command like this example :

---

```
@echo off
Title Get Version from Services.json using PowerShell with a batch file
Set PSCMD=Powershell -C "$(GC Services.json | ConvertFrom-Json).version"
@for /f %%a in ('%PSCMD%') do set "Ver=%%a"
echo Version=%Ver%
pause
```

Comment: I'm trying to do it using batch script.

Comment: @SandeepSangshetty Did you tested it or not yet ? It's just one command that can be used in your batch file, and store your variable as you want.

Answer (score 1):

This pure Batch solution get the values of *all* variables:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Get variables
set "var="
for /F "tokens=1* delims=:{} " %%a in (Services.json) do (
   for %%c in (%%a %%b) do (
      if not defined var (set "var=%%~c") else set "!var!=%%~c" & set "var="
   )
)

rem Show values
echo name=%name%
echo version=%version%
echo description=%description%
```

Output:

```
name=Services
version=1.2.0
description=Customer Services
```

---

**New method** assuming that *"the keyvalue pair is in a single line"*:

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Get variables
set /P "json=" < Services.json
set "json=%json:{=%"
set "json=%json:}=%"
set "json=%json:":"==%"
set %json:,= & set %

rem Show values
echo name=%name%
echo version=%version%
echo description=%description%
```

Comment: See my **New method**... **`:(`**

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to use a structure-aware tool like [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to get content from a JSON file.

```
$version = (jq -r '.version' Services.json)
```